# Is this how you add the digits of multiple numbers? (units, tens, hundreds)

Tags: c++, operators, extract, addition, digits

I just wanna make sure whether this code is good or it needs improvement. What do you all think?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    u = (a%10+b%10+c%10+d%10+e%10+f%10);
    t = (a / 10 % 10 + b / 10 %10 + c / 10 % 10 + d / 10 %10 + e / 10 % 10 + f / 10 %10);
    h = (a / 100 % 10 + b / 100 % 10 + c / 100 % 10 + d / 100 % 10 + e / 100 % 10 + f / 100 % 10);
    
    cout << "The sum of the first digit is: " << u << "\n";
    cout << "The sum of the second digit is: " << t << "\n";
    cout << "The sum of the third digit is: " << h ;
```

Comment: Yes there is room for improvement but [codereview.se] might be a better place to ask. You also might consider creating a [mcve].

Comment: here and at Code Review you should present a complete code. Not so much here, but at code review the code should be correct and working. The code you posted will cause a wall of compiler errors, thats some room for improvement

Comment: I suggest that you get comfortable with arrays and loops.

Comment: Indeed, whenever you are repeating code you should think of a way to make the computer do the repetition. The code should take any amount of numbers of any length, and it could **still** be smaller and more readable even then (although you may need some tricks to display "first", "second" etc.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestion guys! Me and my friend found a solution which is to use the for loop and it made it easier to read :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a bit more generic in at least two ways:

1. Write your code for just one number.
   Then loop for any input numbers.
2. Write your code for adding any `ith` digit.

So, in this case, you could just focus on how to extract the `ith` digit of a given number `n`.
What, as shown in your code, could be done with `(n / divisor) % 10`, where `divisor` would be `exp(10, i)`, `i` starting from `0`.
[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1P9jnr8nh)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // for_each
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <numeric>  // accumulate
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{123'456, 99'999, 100};

    auto sum_of_ith_digit = [](const std::vector<int>& v, size_t i) {
        auto divisor{1};
        while (i != 0) { divisor *= 10; i--; }  // 1 for digit 0, 10 for digit 1, 100 for digit 2...

        return std::accumulate(std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v), 0,  // for each number in v
            [&divisor](auto& total, const auto& n){              // get ith digit
                return total + (n / divisor) % 10;               // and add it to a total,
            });                                                  // then return the total
    };

    auto units = sum_of_ith_digit(v, 0);
    auto tens = sum_of_ith_digit(v, 1);
    auto hundreds = sum_of_ith_digit(v, 2);

    std::for_each(std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v), [first=true](const int n) mutable {
        std::cout << (first ? "v = " : ", ") << n; first = false; });
    std::cout << "\n\tunits = " << units << ", tens = " << tens << ", hundreds = " << hundreds << "\n";
}

// Outputs:
//     v = 123456, 99999, 100
//         units = 15, tens = 14, hundreds = 14
```

The code below should do exactly the same, although it could be a little easier to understand. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ha4fY6nMd)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <vector>

int sum_of_ith_digit(const std::vector<int>& v, size_t i)
{
    // 1 for digit 0, 10 for digit 1, 100 for digit 2...
    int divisor{1};
    while (i != 0) { divisor *= 10; i--; }

    // For each number in v, get ith digit, and add it to a total, then return the total
    int total{0};
    for (int n : v) { total += (n / divisor) % 10; }

    return total;
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{123'456, 99'999, 100};

    int units = sum_of_ith_digit(v, 0);
    int tens = sum_of_ith_digit(v, 1);
    int hundreds = sum_of_ith_digit(v, 2);

    std::cout << "v = ";
    bool first{true};
    for (int n : v)
    {
        if (not first) { std::cout << ", "; }
        else { first = false; }
        std::cout << n;
    }
    std::cout << "\n\tunits = " << units << ", tens = " << tens << ", hundreds = " << hundreds << "\n";
}

// Outputs:
//     v = 123456, 99999, 100
//         units = 15, tens = 14, hundreds = 14
```

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Haha, you are right. I should have started with real loops. I'll update my post.